# Creating a Rails app in Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been trying to install Rails on my Windows PC for the past days. I got the bundle from www.railsinstaller.org and it installed great. When creating a new application I can see that all the app files are created then I get the following error:

```
  bundle install
```

> DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle Fetching gem metadata from
>   https://rubygems.org/.......... Resolving dependencies... 
>   Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0
>   state=SSLv3 read server certificate B : certificate verify failed
>   (https://rubygems.org/gems/rake-10.4.2.gem) An error occurred while
>   installing rake (10.4.2), and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that
>   `gem install rake -v '10.4.2'` succeeds before bundling.

Hoping someone can help with resolving this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [bundle install fails with SSL certificate verification error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246023/bundle-install-fails-with-ssl-certificate-verification-error)

Answer (score 1):

This link could be helpful.

[Creating a Ruby on Rails environment on Windows, in a VM Vagrant Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17060886/creating-a-ruby-on-rails-environment-on-windows-in-a-vm-vagrant-box)

Instead of install ROR directly onto Windows, you might want to use a Linux like OS. Not because Rails environment cannot be setup in Windows. But all the problems you will encounter, especially when most of tools are designed for that when you are not using a Linux like OS and try to mimic that.

But I highly recommend you skip doing all that if you are just trying to learn, and use Nitrous.io, which is an online IDE that gives you all the tool.
IMHO, dealing with Windows in this case is a waste of time.

Comment: Online IDEs like Nitrous and c9.io acting like Linux are the way to go...I have to use Windows at both work and home, and it was the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

First message:

> DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle Fetching gem metadata ..

is a warning message. You read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15601984/3035830).

The main error is encountered while installing rake.

> An error occurred while installing rake (10.4.2), and Bundler cannot
>   continue. Make sure that  gem install rake -v '10.4.2' succeeds before
>   bundling.

To solve this, you should first update Rubygems:

```
gem update --system
```

And then update Bundler:

```
gem install bundler
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply run

```
gem update --system
```

and it fixed. More info please check [bundle install fails with SSL certificate verification error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246023/bundle-install-fails-with-ssl-certificate-verification-error)